# My silverlight Application Can't call the WCF service

Tags: silverlight-3.0, wcf

I have created a simple silverlight application using WCF service.. My service created well and i also test the WCF service with the help of wcftestclient it works fine.. I give a service reference to silverlight also but when i run the silverlight application i can't get the result.

here is silverlight code

```
    void getdatacs(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client cs = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        cs.GetDataCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.GetDataCompletedEventArgs>(getdatacs);
        cs.GetDataAsync(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
    }
```

and here is my WCF code

```
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
```

can any body tell me y i can't get the result.

Comment: Do you get an Exception?

Comment: no. i run the SL application it simple waits nothing happen on the bottom of the browser it says Connection to localhost...

Comment: Have you tried calling the method Synchronously? Is the service running running whilst you're running the Silverlight?

Comment: yes u r right. but the call is Asynchronous...

Comment: y i can't get the result any idea...

Comment: @Raj It appear that the Silverlight ServiceReference lacks a synchronous method. If you leave it running, does it timeout after, say, ten minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the service hosted seperately from the SL app? If so you may need to add a clientaccesspolicy file. see [this link for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct so I would start looking at the configuration of the WCF service.  Double check all the settings in your reference to the WCF service.  I believe your problem is not in the code but elsewhere.  Try removing the input int value to the WCF service and send back any value in the string to eliminate the possibility of any input issue although it looks ok.

I have run across issues like this and it normally turns out to be in the configuration of the WCF service.

Comment: I looked at one of my projects and I have this line of code above the public class line in my WCF service

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]